# Problems with login/Signup on React Native with PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql, react-native

Login/Signup parameters did not work with local server (MySQL). I have a PHP done to link for my server side authentication.

I tried different parameters for the "username" as well as "password" but it just wont register into my database..

Would really appreciate any help on making it work! Thanks a lot!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";
import { Block, Button, Input, Text } from "../components";
import { theme } from "../constants";

// const VALID_USER = "";
// const VALID_PASSWORD = "";

// const login_url = "http://192.168.200.199:80/buildingreg/login.php";
const KEY_STATUS = "status";
const KEY_MESSAGE = "message";
const KEY_FULL_NAME = "full_name";
const KEY_USERNAME = "";
const KEY_PASSWORD = "";
const KEY_EMPTY = "";

export default class Login extends Component {
  state = {
    username: KEY_USERNAME,
    password: KEY_PASSWORD,
    errors: [],
    loading: false
  };

  handleLogin() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { username, password } = this.state;
    const errors = [];

    Keyboard.dismiss();
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    // check with backend API or with some static data

    let reg = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (username === KEY_EMPTY) {
      alert("Please enter Email address");
    } else if (reg.test(username) === false) {
      alert("Username is not correct");
    } else if (password === KEY_EMPTY) {
      alert("Please enter password");
    } else {
      fetch(
        "http://10.55.1.143/buildingreg/login.php",
        {
          method: "post",
          header: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-type": "application/json"
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            // we will pass our input data to server
            username: username,
            password: password
          })
        },
        alert(username, password)
      )
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
          if (responseJson == "ok" || !errors.length) {
            // redirect to profile page
            alert("Successfully Login");
            navigation.navigate("login");
          } else {
            alert("Wrong Login Details");
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error(error);
        });

      //this.setState({ errors, loading: false });
    }
    Keyboard.dismiss();
  }

  render() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const { loading, errors } = this.state;
    const hasErrors = key => (errors.includes(key) ? styles.hasErrors :     null);

    return (
      <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.login} behavior="height">
        <Block padding={[0, theme.sizes.base]}>
          <Text h1 bold>
            Login
          </Text>
          <ScrollView
            showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
            style={{ paddingVertical: theme.sizes.base * 2 }}
          >
            <Block bottom>
              <Input
                label="Username"
                error={hasErrors("username")}
                style={[styles.input, hasErrors("username")]}
                defaultValue={this.state.username}
                onChangeText={username => this.setState({ username })}
              />
              <Input
                secure
                label="Password"
                error={hasErrors("password")}
                style={[styles.input, hasErrors("password")]}
                defaultValue={this.state.password}
                onChangeText={password => this.setState({ password })}
              />
              <Button gradient onPress={() => this.handleLogin()}>
                {loading ? (
                  <ActivityIndicator size="small" color="white" />
                ) : (
                  <Text bold white center>
                    Login
                  </Text>
                )}
              </Button>

              <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Forgot")}>
                <Text
                  gray
                  caption
                  center
                  style={{ textDecorationLine: "underline" }}
                >
                  Forgot your password?
                </Text>
              </Button>
            </Block>
          </ScrollView>
        </Block>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  login: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  input: {
    borderRadius: 0,
    borderWidth: 0,
    borderBottomColor: theme.colors.gray2,
    borderBottomWidth: StyleSheet.hairlineWidth
  },
  hasErrors: {
    borderBottomColor: theme.colors.accent
  }
});
```

Comment: Try removing JSON.stringify() from body and send in key,value

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani Sorry I dont understand.. Can you give an example?

Comment: which library are you using for api calling? axios?

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani Nope. No library involved